# How integrate login page written on react with keycloak custom authenitcation workflow

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, keycloak, single-page-application

I have to implement login for user by email and code from letter. I have keycloak with custom provider. Provider add custom authentication workflow that sends one time code by email. With build in keycloak page authentication works great. But i have to implement login using react application. React application uses `keycloak-js` and `@react-keycloak/web` to integrate with keycloak. Is it possible to integrate react login page with keycloak?